# How do I use GraphQL to query an image from Contentful?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful, gatsby-image

I am building a basic site with Gatsby and have connected it to Contentful. I uploaded 2 assets to Contentful:

First asset looks like:
[image]
[image]

The second asset is 100% identical other than the title which is test-two.

If I use the about query and pass in the URL into an img tag, my image will display. However, I am trying to use GatsbyImage and can't seem to figure out the problem.

I've been trying to follow [this](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/#art-directing-multiple-images) tutorial and using  but I am unable to get anything to render. How does my query need to change in order to use gatsby-image?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are querying for the `url`, `filename` and `contentType`. To be able to use `GatsbyImage` you need to query the node created from Gatsby (which is `gatsbyImageData`) it should be contained in the name of the Contentful asset node. Something like:

```
{
  allContentfulAsset {
    edges {
      node {
        test {
          title
          gatsbyImageData(layout: CONSTRAINED)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Check for the created nodes in the GraphiQL playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`).

Once done, in your component, you should be able to do something like:

```
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

function SomePage({ data }) {
  const image = getImage(data.allContentfulAsset.test)
  return (
    <section>
      <GatsbyImage image={image} alt={`Some alt text`} />
    </section>
  )
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
      allContentfulAsset {
        edges {
          node {
            test {
              title
              gatsbyImageData(layout: CONSTRAINED)
           }
         }
       }
     }
  }
`
```

If the node doesn't appear, check your configurations in the `gatsby-config.js` file.

---

### ⚠️ Disclaimer

Watch out, the tutorial you are trying to use is using `gatsby-image` (from Gatsby v2 backward), where the rendered component is `Img`, imported from `gatsby-image` while you are using `GatsbyImage` (from Gatsby v3 onwards), imported from `gatsby-plugin-image`. The first one is deprecated and the query structure is slightly different. As you can see at the top of the guide you shared:

> The `gatsby-image` package is now deprecated. The new [Gatsby image
> plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image) has better performance, cool new features and a simpler
> API. See the [migration guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/image-migration-guide/) to learn how to upgrade.